# Ember Application Ready state - Application not recognizing method.

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm currently working on a notifications system for an ember application using ember-data and rails as an API. The current setup I have below is trying to call the method 'refresh()' on a notifications controller, at a set interval to fetch the notifications, however the method is not recognized.

Here is the application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
// require jquery.ui.all
//= require handlebars
//= require ember
//= require ember-data
//= require ember-auth
//= require_self
//= require auth
//= require company_backend
//= require ./wepay
//= require_tree .
//= stub polyfills/aight.js
//= stub polyfills/aight.d3.js
//= stub polyfills/mediaqueries.js
//= stub polyfills/pointerevents.js
//= stub polyfills/svg.js

window.CompanyBackend = Em.Application.create({
    ready: function() {
        setInterval(CompanyBackend.BusinessNotifications.refresh(), 2000);
    },
});
```

And here is the BusinessNotifications controller:

```
CompanyBackend.BusinessNotifications = Em.ArrayController.extend({
    refresh: function() {
        alert('in refresh');
    },
});
```

Is there a specific reason I would be getting a has no method 'refresh' error?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the `refresh` method is not called is because nothing is instantiating your `BusinessNotifications` controller.

You could try this to make it work tough:

```
CompanyBackend.businessNotifications = Em.ArrayController.create({
  refresh: function() {
    alert('in refresh');
  },
});

window.CompanyBackend = Em.Application.create({
  ready: function() {
    setInterval(CompanyBackend.businessNotifications.refresh(), 2000);
  }
});
```

The change is small, but vital, you need to create the instance of the controller by yourself with `.create` instead of `.extend` and also notice the lowercased name since this indicates by convention an instance rather then a Class.

Hope it helps.